# Playing sound in Xcode 9.2

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation

I am having some issues with playing sound in Xcode 9.2.
I tried watching few different tutorials and guides, but with no luck.
Either code is outdated, my app with crashes, the sound doesn't work, or it starts and cuts out after few milliseconds...

```
    func updateDiceImages() {

// This is where the actual sound is attempted to play, 
it should be triggered every time the button is pressed. Rest of the app works fine.

        var soundEffect: AVAudioPlayer?

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "rollingDice.wav", ofType:nil)!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            soundEffect = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            soundEffect?.play()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

...

I am just not sure what I am doing wrong, tried tons of variations.
I am completely open to giving any information that I can provide. I didn't paste the whole code so it doesn't bother or swamp the people that try to read it.
Thank you so much for the help! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a taken piece of code from one of my applications, it works completely.

```
import AVFoundation

final class AudioManager {

    private init() { }

    static let shared = AudioManager()

    private var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    enum SoundType {
        case incomingCall
    }

    open func playSound(_ type: SoundType) {
        switch type {
        case .incomingCall:
            playIncomingCall()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Sounds

    private func playIncomingCall() {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "incoming", withExtension: "wav") else { return }
        playSound(url)
    }

    private func playSound(_ url: URL) {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.wav.rawValue)

            guard let player = player else { return }
            player.numberOfLoops = -1 // infinity loop
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
            debugPrint("playSound play sound")
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    open func stop() {
        player?.stop()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually resolved this as it was a bug in a different part of my project. Thank you for your efforts though!